# Custom Action with drop down on MS Bot composer

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-bot-service

I am creating a custom action in the MS Bot composer. The action has to do the following steps.

1. In the properties pane of the custom action, the first input field is a drop down where it has to get the values from a HTTP request as show over here. The dialog designer will choose any of the displayed values. The below highlighted one in the image (Service Name) is the drop down that has to be populated with API request response values (array).
   [image]
2. Based on the selection, the bot will ask for filing some slots by prompting questions. The number and type of prompts will differ based on the user selection.

I am able to create a custom action and add to a bot, but not sure how we can populate values in the properties pane drop down by calling a HTTP request as mentioned in first step. Please help by providing your inputs.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Can you please add more details about the flow of the bot. Also please add details about how are you calling the http request and  the response stored.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the link to event and triggers. https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer/blob/stable/docs/concept-events-and-triggers.md

Please raise an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/BotFramework-Composer/issues) in the bot composer for the team to check.